# Getting jquery ajax to work with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

Am trying to add a record to my database via ajax, but when i try out my code i get
a 500 HTTP error code;
This is the function am submitting to in the controller

```
 function sections_add() {
         $this->load->model('section_model');

         $name = $_POST['name'];
         $slug =  $_POST['slug'];
         $sec = $_POST['description'];

         $options = array(
            "description"=>$sec,
            "slug"=>$slug,
            "category"=>$name
         );

         $this->section_model->add($options);
     }
```

And this the function in the model for adding records

```
function add($options = array()) {
             $this->db->insert('sections',$options);
             if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
        }
```

And this my jquery code
NB:base_url is defined my base url

```
$(function () {
    $('#save_btn').click(function(e) {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var slug = $('#slug').val();
        var des = $('#description').val();

        var data = "name="+name+"slug="+slug+"description="+des;
        var url = base_url+"admin/sections/add";
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            type:'post',
            cache:false,
            data:data,
            success:function() {
                alert('Success');
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault()
    });
});
```

Please what should i do,to get rid of the http 500 error

Comment: Are you sure thats the correct way to use base_url?  Shouldnt it be "url: "http://yoursite.net/admin/sections/add", or "<?php echo site_url('admin/sections/add'); ?>"

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at this quickly, it looks like your submitting to:

admin/sections/add

as opposed to your method name which is sections_add:

admin/sections_add

but that would return a 404 not a 500. If your method name is correct, try passing your data as:

```
var data = {
       name: $('#name').val(),
       slug: $('#slug').val(),
       des: $('#description').val()
    }
```

Comment: my routing rules interpret admin/sections/add as admin/admin/section_add as the controller is in a sub folder called admin

Answer (score 0):

Do you have CSRF protection enabled? If so, you must add csrf_token into POST.

If you're creating forms with form_open from form_helper, look for csrf_token_name hidden variable. Eventually, you can get all form data with http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

May be i'm missing something, but I don't see how you are answering results. No view, no echoing nothing, please try adding...

```
            $data['success'] = $this->section_model->add($options)?1:0;
            echo json_encode($data);
```

in section_add()